# Group table and create measure based on parameter from different rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

bit new to dax and I am struggling in creating a formula.

So I need to write a mathematical calculation which =+(E4+Mx6)/2*33  for the East Silo on the same date and time only.

[image]

So the first one would be 07/11/2022 4:30 am calculation (4+4)/2*33

I tried doing the calculation but i couldn't figure out how to calculate based on the same date field

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Power Query

1. Mark your Parameter and Value columns
2. Transform - Pivot them
3. Add custom column from the new [E4] and [Mx6] columns

M-code should look like this:

```
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
    #"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Parameter]), "Parameter", "Value", List.Sum),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Pivoted Column", "Custom", each ([E4]+[Mx6]) / 2 * 33)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it in DAX, use this measure:

```
Math = 
VAR tbl = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Datetime],
        'Table'[Silo],
        "E4", CALCULATE(
                SUM('Table'[Value]),
                'Table'[Parameter] = "E4"
            ), 
        "Mx6", CALCULATE(                
                SUM('Table'[Value]),
                'Table'[Parameter] = "Mx6"
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        tbl,
        ([E4] + [Mx6]) / 2 * 33
    )
```

[image]